# 'HttpResponseNotFound' object has no attribute 'render'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a django application using django rest framework.

I have the following code:

```
#For get request    
client = APIClient()
client.login(username='username', password='password')
response = client.get('http://103.x.x.x/api/get_last_thread/?format=json')
response.render().content
client.logout()
```

and I have the error of response variable as an empty value (None), I don't know why, if I copy the url to any browser i will have the results.

I have changed the url for a random url and I received the same error, it seems like client.get is not executing the request.

Thank you

Comment: Even if the URL was found you still couldn't call `render()` on it. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Yes!, you are right, I made a mistake because i was testing a little bit about the error. Well, i think that i know what is wrong there.The get function is going to 'http://testserver/api/get_last_thread/?format=json' instance of 'http://103.x.x.x/api/get_last_thread/?format=json'. It is executing the request in the server, that is why a have 404 error. How can I change the server?. I mean I'm working in a server A and I want to get information from the server B.

Comment: Yeah!, I did it using requests module. Thank you guys.